# How to prove this assertion about $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry

Suppose $k \geq 3$, $x$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^k$, $|x-y| = d > 0$, and $r > 0$. Then how to prove the following assertions?

(a) If $2r > d$, then there are infinitely many $z \in \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $$ | z - x | = | z -y | = r.$$

(b) If $2r = d$, then there is exactly one such $z \in \mathbb{R}^k$ for which $$ | z - x | = | z -y | = r.$$

(c) If $2r < d$, then there is no $z \in \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $$ | z - x | = | z -y | = r.$$

How must these statements be modified if $k$ is $2$ or $1$?

Answer (score 2):

Try to think geometrically. What is the collection of all point $z$ such that $|z - x| = r$ for some fixed $r$?

To get some intuition (although you must be careful, particularly given the last question that you ask), it might help to draw this out for $k = 2$ and then try to understand how this is related in the case $k > 2$.

Comment: Simon Rose, for $k=2$, I know that the set $\{z\in\mathbb{R}^2\colon|z-x|=|z-y|=r\}$ is the set of all point(s) of intersection of the circles of radius $r$ with center at points $x$ and $y$ respectively. Similarly, for $k=3$, the set $\{z\in\mathbb{R}^3\colon|z-x|=|z-y|=r\}$ is the set of all the point(s) of intersection of the spheres of radius $r$ centered at $x$ and $y$, respectively.Thus the situation is clear for $k=1$ and for $k=2$. But what about the case of $k>2$?

Comment: Well, for $k = 3$, what happens when you intersect two spheres? What is the resulting shape of the intersection?

For higher $k$, what is a likely analogy?